# Function overloading by swapping order of parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading

About function overriding in C++, the following is legal, as both prototypes have different numbers of parameters:

```
void func(int par1, double par2);
void func(int par1, double par2, double par3);
```

as is (because there is at least 1 parameter of a different type):

```
void func(int par1, double par2);
void func(double par1, double par2);
```

I wondered, just for curiousity, **Is can you overload with the same number of parameters, of the same types, but in a different order?** For example is the following legal:

```
void func(int par1, double par2);
void func(double par1, int par2);
```

**If so, is there any formal document specify it?**

Comment: as long as erasure is different..

Comment: Function's argument types that allow to detect overloading is the same if arguments are both of the same type. So I believe no, it's not possible. I can't cite the standard though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The formal document is the ISO C++ standard and, yes, you can do it.

The entirety of ISO C++11 Chapter 13 is devoted to overloading but the first few paragraphs sum it up nicely:

> When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be *overloaded.* By extension, two declarations in the same scope that declare the same name but with different types are called *overloaded declarations.* Only function and function template declarations can be overloaded; variable and type declarations cannot be overloaded.
>
> When an overloaded function name is used in a call, which overloaded function declaration is being referenced is determined by comparing the types of the arguments at the point of use with the types of the parameters in the overloaded declarations that are visible at the point of use.

Overloading is possible provided the parameter list is different, *including order.* It's different in all three cases you present in your question:

```
{int, double} vs {int, double, double}
{int, double} vs {double, double}
{int, double} vs {double, int}
```

Note that overloading is *not* possible for the two functions:

```
void func(int par1, int par2);
void func(int par2, int par1);
```

since it's really only the *types* that provide uniqueness, not the parameter names. Both of those functions are called `func` and they both have the parameter list `{int, int}`, so they're not unique.

Comment: 8.3.5/5 is also very relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The overloaded functions with the same number of parameters, and the same types, but different order of the paramenters, are allowed:

```
void func(int a, double b) {
}

void func(double a, int b) {
}
```

When we list the exported symbols, we got

```
000000000000025d T _Z4funcdi
000000000000024f T _Z4funcid
```

This means the compiler exports 2 different functions on different addresses. The first one is _Z4funcdi, d means double, and i means int.

Answer (score 1):

> can you overload with the same number of parameters, of the same types, but in a different order?

If you think about it - there's no real reason it wouldn't be legal. The compiler doesn't care about what the function arguments represent, it's not that smart. From that point of view - both of the definitions are different, because they take **different** parameters.

The only thing you have to take care of in this particular case is calling the functions. If you for example have a class that has both `operator double` **and** `operator int` defined, the compiler *will* throw an error if you try to do:

```
myClassWithBothCastOperators a, b;
func(a,b); //<-- ERROR!
```

Even in this case you could however still call the function, by explicitly casting the objects:

```
myClassWithBothCastOperators a, b;
func((int)a, (double)b); //All fine here!
```

However - I don't believe its a good design pattern, and deciding for one propper version would be much clearer for people reading and using your code. As a real life example here, have a look at PHP's `implode`. While in C++ you *can* see what type are the variables, in PHP a variable can hold virtually any type, and analizing/debugging the code becomes a nightmare when `implode`/`explode` are in use with variables with not very meaningful names.